# 'Duplicate connection name' error from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-connection

I've created a SQL Server database to keep track of transactions that will be handled by an application (Windows service) which connects to DB with a Login user.

When I'm trying to connect to the DB, the server replies with

> Duplicate connection name

I've tried to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio and it works, but from the app it doesn't.

Does anyone know any solution for this?

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: The connection string is:
EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :gHostConnect USER $integrated;

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the fact that the user must be mapped to database role membership as **db_owner**. By setting the role, the connection problem was fixed.

[image: set database role membership to db_owner in SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxe10.png)